# Xcode - Sharing extensions and app groups among targets with different developer accounts

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS app in Xcode which has 5 targets (meaning, they're different applications with different `developer accounts`, just using the same codebase).

I have added a `Notification Content Extension` and I want all other targets to use it.

The thing is, this extension also uses a certain `App Group` to share data between it and parent targets. But, because the other targets all have different `developer accounts`, I cannot set a global `App Group` to all apps. Is there a way around it? what's the best practice?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No , it's not possible app groups for targets with the same developer account you may upload your logic to server and share it with apis , you may use UIPasteboard as a workaround but it's not recommended from Apple Docs

Comment: So basically I need to duplicate my extension code over and over for each application target? This sound really stupid and not Apple'ish at all

Comment: Unfortunately , you have to